# Is there a way to dynamically retrieve a website visitor's email address (via them being logged into facebook/google)

Tags: facebook, email, web-applications, scrape, google-account

I've seen this happen before... I've been working inside of a web application that has no explicit affiliation with Google/Facebook, and yet they can get my email address (since I am logged into Google/Facebook).  Perhaps this is via G+ or something?

In any case, I'm building a web app, and am interested in accessing their email addresses (for identification purposes in my database) without having to prompt them to login or have any interaction with my web app.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do that because both facebook and gplus uses oAuth - firstly you have to login with application with email permission (scope).

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/oauth/